# Changing the auto-save frequency when editing files via Tramp / SSH

Tags: ssh, emacs, scp, tramp

I am using Emacs (23.3.1) with Tramp to edit files on a remote SSH server. Right now these files are being auto-saved / auto-uploaded about once every minute. During each upload, anything I type does not show until after the upload is finished, and it's getting a bit distracting.

Is there any way to change the auto-save / auto-upload frequency for Emacs with Tramp? It can be a Tramp-specific or editor-wide setting — whatever works best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Control.html#Auto-Save-Control

Basically, you want to set `auto-save-interval` to the number of characters typed between auto-saves.